# How can I add a TreeNode to a JTree constructed with the default constructor?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to add a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to a `JTree`, but I couldn't figure out how I could do that with the default `JTree` constructor.

```
final JTree tree = new JTree();
final DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

...
```

What am I missing? I'd love to achieve that without the use of the `JTree(TreeNode)` constructor.

Comment: `final Tree tree = new JTree();` does this compile? JTree does not extend from Tree

Comment: Use a constructor that takes a TreeNode, and then add nodes to *that* node

Comment: and read the [JTree Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) and the API for JTree and DefaultMutableTreeNode for the details.

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter Of course it's final `JTree tree = new JTree()`, I was just typing too fast. And no, I don't want to use the `JTree(TreeNode)` constructor.

Comment: `"And no, I don't want to use the JTree(TreeNode) constructor"` -- but why? You appear to be asking -- "how do I create a tree that allows adding nodes, but I only want to use a constructor that creates an inflexible non-mutable tree". The constructor is there for a good reason -- use it!

Comment: You can't do this with the JTree but would need to access its model and call the model's methods. See edit to answer. Please ask if any questions

Comment: Alright, I understood. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the JTree constructor that takes a TreeNode object, and pass in a DefaultMutableTreeNode object. The DefaultMutableTreeNode class is the one that allows addition or removal of nodes, not the JTree class. The API will show you this.  Per the JTree API, the constructor that you're using `new JTree();` creates a JTree object with a "sample" model -- why would you want this?

If you insist on your way of doing things, you can by getting the TreeModel from the JTree, casting to DefaultTreeModel, and then calling its `setRoot(...)` method. But this does carry some risk with the casting, and you will want to test to make sure the model is the correct type first before casting.

```
final JTree tree = new JTree();
TreeModel model = tree.getModel();
if (model instanceof DefaultTreeModel) {
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("root");
    treeModel.setRoot(root);
}
```